# Installing noxim on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, 15.04

When I am trying to install `noxim` on `Ubuntu`, the Error message on terminal is :

```
no yaml  configuration file found! 
Use -config to load examples from config_examples folder.
```

In addition I have a `config_examples` folder, but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is one mistake in command

```
bash <(wget -qO- --no-check-certificate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidepatti/noxim/master/other/setup/ubuntu.sh)
```

in `ubnutu.sh` file second line is

```
cp ../config_examples/config.yaml .
```

it should be

```
cp ../config_examples/other/config.yaml .
```

solution :
copy `config.yaml` from `noxim/config_examples/other/` to `/noxim/bin/` 
then go to `/noxim/bin/` and run command

```
./noxim
```

it will show completion message like

```
Loading configuration from file config.yaml
Running with default parameters (use '-help' option to see how to override them)
Reset...
 done! Now running for 10000 cycles...
Noxim simulation completed.
```

if you did some changes while debugging this problem or you are going to install on fresh system then do following steps :
download `ubuntu.sh` file

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidepatti/noxim/master/other/setup/ubuntu.sh
```

open file `ubuntu.sh` and go to second last line and change it 
`cp ../config_examples/config.yaml .` to   `cp ../config_examples/other/config.yaml .`  and save it 
make it executable using command

```
chmod +x ubuntu.sh
```

then run it

```
./ubuntu.sh
```

Comment: now it's better =)

Comment: Tomorrow I have an upvote for you, today they are unfortunately all consumed. ;)

Comment: Please, don't use exclamation marks. ;)

Comment: Thanks a.b for helping me in installing systemc on Ubuntu.